# Call a block of code once every 10ms in a while loop without stopping the loop c++

Tags: c++, loops, timer

So I'm trying to run a block of code once every 10ms in a while loop without stopping the loop (sleeping).

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
while (true) {
    if (should_run_the_10ms_code) {
        // some code (once every 10 ms)
    }

    // some other code (every tick)
}
```

Comment: Use a timer like, for example, [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimer.html).

Comment: @JesperJuhl This could work but I don't want to have an entire library for something so simple

Comment: Then implement similar functionality yourself.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If I would have known how or found some code I would not have asked this question

Comment: How should your program behave if, for example due to high system load, executing the code block gets delayed by 5ms, so that it only executes after 15ms instead of 10ms. How long should it then wait to be executed next time? Should it be only 5ms instead of 10ms, in order to "catch up"? Or should it be 10ms again?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel It should be 10ms. The main idea is so that the code doesn't run as fast as possible but at a controlled speed. The consistency doesn't really matter. (it shouldn't be extremely unconcistent though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::chrono::steady_clock::now`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now) gives you the current time from a monotonic clock. Here is a relatively simple way to use it:

```
auto timer = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
while (true) {
    auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> timer_diff_ms = timer - now;
    if (timer_diff_ms >= 10.0) {
        // some code (once every 10 ms)
        timer = now;
        // or
        // timer = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        // if the "some code" takes a bit of time
    }

    // some other code (every tick)
}
```

Note that `timer_diff_ms` might be much greater than 10 if something lenghty happens between the `now()` calls (might be in the "some other code" part, might be completely unrelated to your program).

You can also use `std::chrono::milliseconds` instead of `std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>` if you don't need a `double` (it will be some integer type).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Making this myself would have been a pain since I don't have experience with timers in c++

Comment: Instead of `timer = now` you can advance timer by 10 ms. That way you are guaranteed, over the long run, to get 100 calls per second